# "Achieving this will be not easy" or "Achieving this will not be easy"?

Tags: word-order

*Achieving this will be not easy* or *Achieving this will not be easy*, which is correct?

I feel that *Achieving this will be not easy* is the correct way, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Achieving this will be not easy.
2. Achieving this will not be easy.

To negate the main verb, you need to put “not” before the main verb, as in #2.

It is also valid to negate the adjective, as in #1, but this has a slight different meaning and is not as common except in the special case of double negation.

Answer (score 1):

"Achieving this will not be easy" is the more natural way of saying it.  Normally I would not see the verb precede the "not" unless it were a command, and it would be correct but old-fashioned.

For example, "Go not into the house" would be correct grammatically, but not something people would say unless they were deliberately trying to sound old-fashioned.  Modern use would require "Do not go into the house."